# QGIS focus multiple vertices in one point

Tags: qgis, linestring, vertices

I have a bunch of lines, which have been offset. The tool in fact works fine, but I noticed, that the lines end in different places, whereas I want them to be terminated in one place.
The image below is what I would like to have:

[image]

and another image shows my current problem:

[image]

which I would like to solve.

I use the Verte Tool for the current layer, where I select all nodes considered in the area. Unfortunately, they can be moved just on the basis as they stand. It means, that I can move them whereas the distance between them is still kept. I am wondering about an option, which could allow me to place all of them at some point - focus them on some midpoint of something. Is it possible?

Comment: How do you offset the lines?

Comment: I use offset curve in the advanced toolbar.

Comment: Can you share a sample dataset? For example export selected features as wkt, paste the wkt strings in your question

Answer (score 1):

You could use the geometry generator to create new geometries based on the current one or simply modify the symbology.

Now given that I don't have access to your data I based my code on the fact that your lines are in a different layer and that your point of interest is a single point. This could be changed.

Here is a potential solution to use as an expression.

```
make_line( 
start_point( $geometry),
end_point( line_substring( $geometry,0,0.2)), 
array_first( overlay_nearest('anchor_0211b7b7_8fff_4ffc_834c_50fb3eb423ae',$geometry)))
```

The make line just collect the points, I assume you wanted to maintain the start point and have the line converge based on a certain distance from their end point. The `line_substring` generate those shorter lines and we simply collect the last point. And lastly the `array_first(overlay_nearest())`
helps to get the closes point from the anchor layer (use the appropriate one in your layer table instead). Thus making the lines converge on that feature.

Comment: I used the "geometry by expression" but it says, that the function is not known.

Comment: @MKR everything should be standard, which version are you using? The first arg of Overlay_nearest ad the last of line_substring should be changed.